# Teamviewer not working (no connection)

Tags: server, ssh, connection, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I installed teamviewer on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I downloaded from the Teamviewer homepage the 32-bit version and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
```

I usually use this machine directly (not remotely), but, occasionally I log in remotely. In this case I want to start a `teamviewer` server remotely, to connect to my machine.

So, I run `teamviewer` via a `ssh -X` session on the server (ssh session with X support) in order to prepare the server for incoming connection.

Unfortunately, the status bar tells me `Not ready. Please check your connection`. I tried also setting an account but it tells me to check my connection and fails.

I used teamviewer before from the same machine and it never give me the same error. Can it be related to the fact I am running it via a `ssh` connection?

I tried also to change the ownership of `/opt/teamviewer9` and `~/.config/teamviewer9` to my user (it was `root:root`) but with no results.

Thanks

Comment: restart the system once

Comment: It worked, but why? The daemon started as I installed it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Tamil Selvan's comment, restarting does indeed fix this on *buntu, with a fresh install of Teamviewer.

I had the same issue with an AWS EC2 instance.